# Position an element with relative x but absolute y coordinate

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this layout: [image]

So I have three Material UI `Columns` in a row, which have different widths I don't know in advance. Now I want to place `Button` (`"Create Item"`) at the bottom of the screen (absolute), but horizontally centered to the middle (i.e. the main) `Column`. The content of this middle column can be short, or even more than fits on a screen, and is scrollable in that case.

The problem: The `Button` positioning does not work.

- Placing the `Button` with a `fixed` position doesn't center it horizontally at the middle column but the screen.
- Placing it at the bottom of the middle column's content with a `relative` position and `textAlign: 'center'` messes with the button vertical position (it can even get pushed out of the screen if the middle column's content is too long).
- Placing it at the top of the middle column with `textAlign: 'center', transform: 'translateY(85vh)'` looks only nice until you start scrolling down and you see the `Button` moving up.

How can I achive this "floating" behavior just regarding the vertical position?

Edit - here's a minimal example:

```js
<Grid container>
  <Grid xs={2}>
    <Box style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <div>Left Column for Navigation</div>
      <div>Nav 1</div>
      <div>Nav 2</div>
    </Box>
  </Grid>

  <Grid xs={6}>
    <Grid
      style={{
        zIndex: 9001,
        position: 'relative',
        textAlign: 'center',
        maxHeight: 0,
        transform: 'translateY(85vh)',
      }}
    >
      <Button>Create Item</Button>
    </Grid>
    <Box style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <Grid>Main Column</Grid>
      <Grid>Many Items,</Grid>
      <Grid>it might even</Grid>
      <Grid>require scrolling</Grid>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} xs={4}>
    <div>Right Column For Context-Related Stuff</div>
    <Grid>Context Entry 1</Grid>
    <Grid>Context Entry 2</Grid>
    <Grid>Context Entry 3</Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In this example, the `Button` `"Create Item"` would get scrolled away if there where more items in the main column, but I want it floating at a fixed y-position at the screen.

Comment: Can you add code or share minimum reproducible example?

Comment: @ShikharAwasthi I've added an example. I apologize if it's to verbose, bugged or anything. I've just inherited that project and never done frontend stuff, let alone react, before.

Comment: _"Placing it at the bottom of the middle column's content with a relative position and textAlign: 'center' messes with the button vertical position (it can even get pushed out of the screen if the middle column's content is too long)"_ - then don't apply scrolling to the middle column, but wrap the content into an extra element, and apply scrolling to that instead? Make sure your middle column is as high as the viewport (100vh), position the button _absolute_ at the bottom. And for the additional wrapper, specify a max-height of 100% or 100vh minus enough space for the button (use 'calc()`)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, that seem to help. Not sure I got everything right, because I had to center the button with `relative`, and now the window's scrollbar isn't the one for the main column anymore (in the real application, in the minimal example it is), but it's definitly a step forward! If you post your idea as answer I'll gladly accept it!